# Is it possible to drive two monitors at the same time from the same DVI-I output using a dongle?

Tags: multiple-monitors, dvi

I mean one monitor using the analog and the other the digital signal of the DVI-I output of regular AMD or Nvidia cards.

The dongles I refer to are those that go into the DVI-I out and at the opposite side they expose both the DVI and the VGA connectors.

[image]

I have always assumed only one at a time is possible, but after seeing that such dongles exist I began to wonder if this assumption is correct.

Through searching I've found that there exist machines called "thin clients", and at least one of them supposedly support such functionality, but for regular PCs I couldn't find a definitive yes or no answer before going ahead and buying the dongle.

Comment: More than likely that is a dual link dvi cable that splits the dual signal into 2 separate signals, which will result in lower resolution for both. The graphics card must support dual link also.

Comment: @moab I don't think it is a dual link. You can't convert half of a dual-link to analog without use of converter chip. But there is no power for such a chip provided by a normal DVI output. Off course it could be a proprietary non-standard DVI output on the computer that provides power on some pins, but why would you do something like that as the video-card itself already contains the electronics to drive the analog part of the DVI connector?. Dual-Link DVI-I outputs do exist (I have an old Matrox card with one), but the dual-link only applies to the digital part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You assume correctly that only one of the signals would work.
To my knowledge video-cards that supply both analog and digital signal to the DVD-I simultaneously don't exist at all.
Normally the card would sense if the monitor is digital (monitor will talk back and identify itself and indicate which resolutions it supports) and the card will disable the analog out.
If there is no digital monitor the card will assume analog and switch its output driver accordingly.

These splitters are just 2 dumb converters that share the DVD-I plug.

Answer (score 1):

You should have given a link to the example product, and not only to its image,
because it is hard to guess what it does.

If the product in the image was called "adapter", then it is to be used with only
one display at a time. An adapter just adapts one single stream to another single
stream.

The product should have been called "splitter", meaning that it splits/mirrors
one input into two identical outputs. You cannot use the two outputs of the card,
so you need to split one of them, the DVI, and the other goes unused.

A random example of such a splitter is
[StarTech.com Wyse Compatible DVI Splitter Cable](https://www.amazon.co.uk/StarTech-com-8in-Wyse-Splitter-Cable/dp/B00KILTAT8),
which does "DVI-I to DVI-D and VGA - M/F"
(no recommendation intended):

[image]

You should find a splitter that fits the cables needed for your two monitors.
Pay attention to the plugs on the ends of the cables when searching for the
right splitter.

Comment: This is incorrect: Splitters like these are just 2 converters sharing the DVI-I plug. It depends on the vido-card which of the 2 (DVI-D or VGA) gets output. the other end doesn't get any signal at all. To my knowledge there isn't ANY video-card on the market that sends signal to the digital and analog output simultaneously.

Comment: @Tonny: You misunderstood my answer, so I improved the text. We are both saying the same thing, just that I'm giving an example of what can be done. The adapter (or splitter) given by the poster does the same: DVI to two outputs. Please undo the downvote.

Comment: @harrymc I actually meant two monitors each displaying unique images, rather than one just mirroring the other (be through a passive or active adapter).  In this case both the passive dongles shown in this thread would work (if a card could provide two signals at the same time that is, which they can't apparently), as they just link the proper pins at each end of the cable.

Comment: A DVI-I connector has single DDC channel to detect whether the single connected monitor is analog or digital and drivers will enable the corresponding output. It cannot read EDID from two monitors that are simultaneously connected. This is apparent from the product user reviews - one connector has a picture, it does not split.

Comment: This depends on the video card. Which is yours?

Comment: @harrymc Much better now. :-)  I removed the downvote.